# request.body is undefined in node post request

Tags: node.js, request

I am trying to handle post ajax request at node server. My problem is, I am getting request body 'undefined'. kindly help me to understand if I am doing wrong. Following is the code I am using.

- Ajax request code:

function sendRequest() {

```
    let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = 'http://<hostname>:3000/checkRequest';    
    let data = {};
    data.name = "nameString";
    data.age = "ageString";        
    http.open('POST', url, true);        
    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.send(JSON.stringify(data));   
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    };   
}
```

- Request handler code:

  ```
  // create express app
  const app = express();

  // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

  // parse application/json
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  // middleware route that all requests pass through
  app.use((request, response, next) => {
      console.log('Server info: Request received');

      let origin = request.headers.origin;

      // only allow requests from trusted origins
      if (originWhitelist.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
          response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
      }

      // only allow get and post requests, separate methods by comma e.g. 'GET, POST'
      response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
      response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
      response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

      // push through to the proper route
      next();
  });

  app.post('/checkRequest', (request, response) => {
           console.log(request.body.name) //undefined
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to make the following changes:

1: Use the content type json:
   http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');

2: I need to add request type 'OPTIONS' in my node application because if we change default content-type browser send an extra 'OPTIONS' type request before sending actual post request (reference request screen shot added).

For more details refer: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Flowchart_showing_Simple_and_Preflight_XHR.svg

Updated allow methods are:

response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');

[image: My request screen]

Answer (score 2):

You're sending the result of `JSON.stringify` with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you want to submit JSON change the content type to `application/json`. If you want to submit url encoded use `new URLSearchParams(data).toString()` instead of `JSON.stringify(data)`.

I personally recommend sending data as JSON.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString

Comment: You are correct ... I need to change "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" with "application/json". But still its not working!!!